# HP Vertica database in concurrent query environment?

Tags: database, vertica

I tried to using Vertica for an web application which handle about 3600 times simple database query per second, but the performance turned out to be very low for concurrent query. The machine is very powerful, 128G ram and 40 core cpu.
So i just want to know is Vertica simply designed for OLAP and not suitable for OLTP application？

Does anyone has hand-on experience on using vertica for OLTP situation?

All I find on the Web are about how powerful the vertica for analytic query.

Comment: Who did you consult initially about Vertica's fit with your needs? What else would you be doing with the database than serving up "simple" queries?

Answer (score 0):

Vertica was purpose built for analytic workloads, not transactional. That said, there are very narrow use cases where you can certainly tune the environment to achieve higher concurrency, but with a larger cluster (not just a single machine) and probably not to the number you've mentioned.

You should also better define if you're looking for parallelism or concurrency.